# Make a pull request / reset in gitkraken

Tags: git, gitkraken

I've tried to make a pull to my project in gitkraken but this message keeps showing up:
[image: pull]

and also when i try disc ard all changes I get this:
[image: reset].
 Any advice?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the text contents of those error messages. It'll make things easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You could n't `pull` because of unsaved changes which gitkraken tried to `stash` away.

Both the errors were caused because gitkraken was unable to get access to those files.

Try checking if any other program is currently accessing those files.
Make sure you are running the system as root.